# Calculate date diff using same date filed column

Tags: r, datetime

I want to find the total sum of running minutes of a battery per month and year. For this I have the following condition:

If Battery.voltage < 50 then "Yes, otherwise "No.

Note: For calculating the total sum of mins, we can the time stamp column which  is day, month, year, hour, mins.

This is my data:

```
#          Time.stamp Battery.voltage Condition
# 1  01/04/2016 00:00              51        No
# 2  01/04/2016 00:01              52        No
# 3  01/04/2016 00:02              45       Yes
# 4  01/04/2016 00:03              48       Yes
# 5  01/04/2016 00:04              49       Yes
# 6  01/04/2016 00:05              55        No
# 7  01/04/2016 00:06              54        No
# ...

structure(list(
  Time.stamp = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L), 
                         .Label = c("01/04/2016 00:00", "01/04/2016 00:01", "01/04/2016 00:02", "01/04/2016 00:03", 
                                    "01/04/2016 00:04", "01/04/2016 00:05", "01/04/2016 00:06", "01/04/2016 00:07", 
                                    "01/04/2016 00:08", "01/04/2016 00:09", "01/04/2016 00:11", "01/04/2016 00:12", 
                                    "01/04/2016 00:13"), class = "factor"), 
  Battery.voltage = c(51L, 52L, 45L, 48L, 49L, 55L, 54L, 52L, 51L, 49L, 48L, 47L, 45L, 50L, 51L), 
  Condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
                        .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor")), 
  .Names = c("Time.stamp", "Battery.voltage", "Condition"), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

My expected output is something like this:

```
Month    year    Sum of mins running in battery
Jan      2016     350min
Feb      2016     450min
etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unfortunately, your sample data is not very representative of your problem statement, as it only includes data for one day. It would have been beneficial to provide some code that generates random data for sufficient entries (i.e. dates).**

That aside, you could adapt the following solution (here I assume your timestamp format is `"DD/MM/YYYY"`):

```
df %>%
    mutate(
        Time.stamp = as.POSIXct(Time.stamp, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),
        byday = format(Time.stamp, "%d/%m/%Y"),
        bymonth = format(Time.stamp, "%d/%m"),
        byyear = format(Time.stamp, "%Y")) %>%
    group_by(byday) %>%
    summarise(sum.running.in.mins = sum(Condition == "Yes"))
## A tibble: 1 x 2
#  byday      sum.running.in.mins
#  <chr>                    <int>
#1 01/04/2016                   7
```

Here we create columns `byday`, `bymonth` and `byyear` according to which you can group entries and calculate the sum of total running time per group. In above example, I calculate the total running time by day; to get the total running time per month, you would replace `group_by(byday)` with `group_by(bymonth)`.

Comment: In this code it will give sum(count of occurences). But I want to sum based on mins in time stamp. One issue here time.stamp is random in mins. data is taken 1 min once and for another data time stamp is taken in 5 min once. So can I sum up the battery usage based on sum of mins?

Comment: @KrishnaMoorthy Every row corresponds to a timestamp for every minute, so `sum(Condition == "Yes")` will give you the total minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I deeply appreciate